# Automatically re-sorting tree

Tags: c++

Is there a way to have a tree which automatically re-sorts its elements, or when calling some method (not when inserting new element)?

I would like to have a tree, i.e. a set, of small structures like this:

```
struct item
{
    int value;
};
```

The set:

```
set<item> items;
auto p = items.insert(...);
```

And I would like to have a map holding iterators to the items held in set:

```
map<name, items::iterator> items_map;
items_map["abc"] = p.first;
```

After some time I would like to do lookup on the map and get the pointer to the item held in set to increase its value.

```
auto iter = items_map["abc"];
iter->value++;
```

Now I would like the set to automatically rearrange so that it reflects the updated value, I mean I would like the set to automatically sort itself (or after calling some method).

Is there a way to do so with current containers in STL?

Comment: So like `change_priority()` in a priority_queue?

Comment: you cant change items in a set anyway. storing iterators in a map feels like a bad idea too. just put the items in the map

Comment: Since [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) holds unique elements, you should think about what incrementing an `item`'s `value` would do...

Comment: Also, maybe a `std::set<std::pair<std::string,item>>` might help? or a `std::set<item>` where `struct item { std::string name, int value};` with some comparator? OR, `std::map<std::string, int>` where the `int` is analogous to `value`?

Comment: Why storing iterators to a set is a bad idea?

Comment: because iterators get invalidated all the time

Comment: @Charles - thats we you cant even do it, they are const

Comment: The documentation says that when inserting new elements to a set the iterators are not invalidated.

Comment: @YotKay but can you ensure that the iterators are _always_ valid?

Comment: Std set and map are implemented as a binary search tree, probably red black tree. They are always sorted after using insert.

Comment: @pm100: storing iterators is bad if they are containers where their invalidation is frequent, such as `vector`... storing iterators to elements into `map`, `set` or `list` is perfectly fine, as they are invalidated only when the element itself is erased.

Comment: If the elements of the set are const then I could store pointers to items instead. It would work to update the value of item. But not to re-sort the items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to do lookup on the map and get the pointer to the item held in set to increase its value.
>
> Is there a way to do so with current containers in STL?

No. Elements of a `std::set` may not be modified. As such, the iterators are constant, and you couldn't use them to modify the elements.

The simple way to achieve similar effect would be to remove the old element, and insert a modified copy.  However, any iterator that used to point to the old element will of course be invalidated by the removal of the element and will not point to the modified one.

> Is there a way to have a tree which automatically re-sorts its elements, or when calling some method (not when inserting new element)?

Sure, but there is no such structure in the standard library.

Comment: What kind of structure would you suggest to build such thing on my own?

Comment: You haven't explained much what you are using the structure for, but since you apparently need to look up by word, and also need sorted traversal by some other predicate, it seems that you need a multi-index container.

Comment: Like Boost MultiIndex?

Comment: According to this page (https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.multiindex), the Boost MultiIndex provides a method "modify" which does exactly what I wanted! That is great. "All interfaces will be notified and can calculate new hash values."